# Oracle query - Taxonomy

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables-

SUBJECT_TABLE

SUBJECT_UID SUBJECT | PARENT_SUBJECT_UID| SUBJECT_LEVEL

---

SUBJECT_ITEM_TABLE

SUBJECT_ITEM_UID | SUBJECT_UID | ACTIVE_DATE

Requirement:

- I need to get all the subjects from SUBJECT table which has items with ACTIVE_DATE lesser than Current Date available in SUBJECT_ITEM table.
- If a parent subject doesn’t have any items available but if the child does, then I need the parent subjects too.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check only children rows for each parent then you can use this query:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c30d/1)

```
with st as (
  select subject_uid suid, parent_subject_uid puid,
      nvl((select 1 from subject_item si 
        where si.subject_uid = st.subject_uid and active_date<sysdate ), 0) it
    from subject_table st)
select suid, puid, it from st 
  where it=1 or exists (select 1 from st st2 where it=1 and puid=st.suid)
```

But if you want to perform check for children, grandchildren (and so on) then you need hierarchical subquery:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c30d/3)

```
with st as (
  select subject_uid suid, parent_subject_uid puid,
      nvl((select 1 from subject_item si 
        where si.subject_uid = st.subject_uid and active_date<sysdate ), 0) it
    from subject_table st),
sh as (
  select suid, puid, it, connect_by_root(suid) root from st 
    connect by prior suid= puid )
select suid, puid, it from st 
  where it=1 or exists (select 1 from sh where it=1 and root=st.suid)
```

In my example row with id=2 has no items, his children too, but grandchild meets criteria, so second query shows id=2 too.

Comment: The second query worked as I had to check for children, grandchildren etc. And trust me, i tried to vote , but did not have enough "reputation" :(

Comment: OK, thanks. And remeber - if your question is precise you increase chances of a correct answer.